# feedback on webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, css

What is the best way, or existing snipets/libs (free/open source) of doing something like this
[image]

Technologies I would like to have in this is jquery, CSS3. etc..

Comment: i see it in this site : http://diem-project.org/  explore the code

Comment: If you really want to do it right, provide a non-Javascript way too to give feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any modal box to make it work. Just some implement.

Here live demo http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/eXDGE/

I use [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/08/jquery-animated-feedback-tab-thingy/) while googling. It seems they made a plugin of that as well. It could be a good start, unless someone has a complete solution.